# Translating urls Django

Tags: django, path, translation, django-urls

I'm using `gettext_lazy as _` for translating urls in Django. My question is how can I translate only particular single string, for example:
`path(_('<int:document_id>/preview/<uuid:uuid_link>/')`  here i want to get only **/preview/** for translation in my **django.po** file not the whole string?

Comment: no. if you want to do something like that, you'd probably want to do it by redirects.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why not just create translations for the entire url, and leave the arguments as they are?